# Controlling flex chart axes

Tags: apache-flex, charts, renderer

I want to use small flex charts with just 3 labels, for example a chart over the past 2 hours , with 3 horizontal label, as shown below:

```
  |       |        |    
9:46    10:46    11:46
```

(of course, there are more than 3 values to display!)

I have been told this is not trivial, but how would you do it?

Also, do you know of any books that present how to achieve sophisticated layouts in Flex?  The books I have found are code-oriented and usually limit formatting to a minimum, and it's not always straightforward to connect the names of attributes to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in the online [Flex Language Guide](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/index.html) at the [AxisRenderer](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/charts/AxisRenderer.html) class.

It also has some helpful sample code and output.

Comment: The example I found in the documentation of AxisRenderer did not answer my question. I believe the solution involves overwriting the constructor. This is why I asked the question on this forum. Flex can do wonderful things easily, but some simple things are devilishly hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the CategoryAxis type?  Using this you can explicitly set the labels.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need "[Bindable]" before every variable you want to use as a dataProvider, so one more before *labels*.